# How print nearest object?

Tags: arcpy, nearest-neighbor

I have point on map. I want found nearest object. Code works perfect. System show 1 occurence. But how get it?

```
point = arcpy.Point(5285360.478599999, 5310336.491400003)
ptGeometry = arcpy.PointGeometry(point)
x = arcpy.analysis.Near(ptGeometry, opori_path, None, "NO_LOCATION", "NO_ANGLE", "PLANAR", "NEAR_FID;NEAR_DIST;NEAR_FC")
```

[image]

Comment: I would guess you can treat x as a tuple, so  it's `x[0]` for the first feature, which you can print with `print(x[0])`.

Comment: The `Near` tool/function expects a feature layer as input (not a geometry).  It will actually add fields to this input layer (if they don't already exist) and the details of the nearest feature will be added to these new fields for each of the input features (including the FID and feature class of the nearest feature).  See:  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/near.htm